# Salesforce lightning components qa automation

Tags: test-automation, selenium

I am new to Salesforce testing, we have an automation suite written with protractor currently and its working fine with classic version of sf.

However now most of the new requests are towards lightning and also classic components are migrated to lightning mode. Has anybody tried and tested ‘AutonomIq’ from saucelabs? Any other good low cost maintainance options will be appreciated.

Comment: Please avoid using tags which have nothing to do with your question.

Answer (score 1):

We (I work for Salesforce.org) build and apply a sophisticated browser automation testing process using [Robot Framework](https://cumulusci.readthedocs.io/en/stable/robot.html). Our free and open source tool CumulusCI ships with a library of Robot keywords for interacting with Salesforce Lightning UIs.

Many of our open source products have Robot Framework integration tests, which you can view - [NPSP](https://github.com/SalesforceFoundation/NPSP/tree/master/robot/Cumulus/tests) is an example.